Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x1772
I'm using trying to execute swap txn on pump.fun.
I've generated the instructions using Solana Swap
For some reason, sometimes I am getting this error code.
{
   "bundleId":"9ada11df022acae423f43bf4e75998444a319806087ec55511ff63c586e18252",
   "rejected":{
      "simulationFailure":{
         "txSignature":"2j5RteS35ELmJKyNh9tRaKmBQQTpJeNx3s1tUYTRkPjAPiM4arxKFRt63dFyD4dZn5Cx1DkEwn7br5YB4XHHnACw",
         "msg":"A transaction in the bundle failed to execute: [signature=2j5RteS35ELmJKyNh9tRaKmBQQTpJeNx3s1tUYTRkPjAPiM4arxKFRt63dFyD4dZn5Cx1DkEwn7br5YB4XHHnACw, error=Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x1772]"
      }
   }
}

How can I get rid of it?
What does it even mean?
I checked with other similar error txs using google search, found 3 such cases

https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2mTGemsyD8dsSPxDKGgenSfrUTcUg9cdkZAdUeF8xq4HEMQoMn5vQm1G73exk8Uv1GmUx8DGj46Wuqqyft8fjRxZ?cluster=mainnet
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/15dxCTAqzx3ujCno6xbfttmiPDzRShNKrypK8K2rd576YGivhNTTueXS37rtXZK5Xcc37izX6aXrXp2qhhx2oXh?cluster=mainnet-beta
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3Vq17GPy8kLGHCSnQx3q1zKwjhJfros2jrdoksayd7RHnEyvJSDGK4CdoYpcWPm7oU1SUVLcyVLJTkzn7nFD8j6h

But couldn't get more info on how to counter it or anything.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)
